# How do I write quotes in VBA codes?

Tags: excel, vba, string

Trying to write in the cell the following code, using VBA:

```
=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];"<>0")
```

I've tried both ways I found on stackoverflow:

```
=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];""<>0"")
=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];" & Chr(34) & "<>0" & Chr(34) & ")
```

Neither of them worked.
Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't look like VBA. It looks like a cell formula. At any rate. `=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];"""<>0""")` or `=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];chr(34) & "<>0" & chr(34))` should work

Comment: `cell.formula = "=countif(Table1[@[Jan]:[Dec]];""<>0"")"`